# React UI framework VS pure CSS with styled-components lib

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I'm a new developer with about six months of experience in the backend side, some months ago I started a company with a business partner, we are developing a business intelligence solution, since then we was working at the back-end part, I have started at the front-end world about 1 month ago, I did a React course where I learned router, redux saga, hooks and other things as styled-components. Our intention is to recreate the front-end part of the system which current is a MVP did by one freelancer.

As I do not have any experience at the frontend, we are planning to use some React theme, this way we decrease the chance of doing wrong decisions during the development of the pages, as in the architecture side.

I'm searching for a dashboard theme based in React which I can edit to our needs, after talk with some friends with more experience, we decided build the pages using pure CSS together with styled-components because I'm a little familiar with it (at the React course I did some exercises with React and styled-components), also because it is easy to use, easy to future developers maintain, also for faster development, as will not need to create a design pattern from scratch and also some front-end developers told me they develop faster in pure CSS in comparison to use some UI framework. Also a reason to do not use UI frameworks is because our costumers use the solution more from mobile than desktop, then soon we will need to create the an app with React Native and styled-components are compatible with it, and Material UI and Bootstrap frameworks that are the most famous framework are not by compatible with React Native by default according the research I did.

The problem is I'm not finding a dashboard theme without UI framework, all  the dashboard themes that I have found are UI frameworks as Material UI and Bootstrap, so I'm asking my self why I can't find dashboard themes using only styled-components, without UI frameworks, maybe because is not common and also is not a good practice create a system not using some UI framework? or it is normal and also is a good practice?

If yes, some suggestion where I can find it?  Preferable open source. Other thing which I'm asking my self, why does not have or why is not popular open source themes at GitHub?

Comment: @ian-kemp why the rollback on the spelling errors?

Comment: @JasonAller Because this question violates the site's rules and should be closed. Minor cosmetic editing has no chance of making it conform to said rules, therefore said editing is a waste of time. In short: don't polish a turd.

Comment: I fixed the spelling again and hope that Leonardo will read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) so that they can learn why asking for a library recommendation isn't considered a good question here. They could always take that question to the software recommendations site https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ after checking that it is on topic there.

Answer (score 0):

### Design is ALOT of work

In my opinion it's probably a mistake to not use a design framework **especially** when you don't have extended knowledge and resources in design & UX. A design framework makes it alot easier to create a consistent, responsive and polished look especially if you are not a design professional / don't have someone exclusively working on design & UX.  Design is alot of work especially when designing for mobile, users expect a certain amount of fluidity and animation that is time intensive and hard to get right when you are unexperienced. Talking about user expectations; this is is another reason why using a framework can be handy. If you use a framework that is well known you'll allready know how other apps using this framework are structured and it will be easier to find a structure for you own app. On the other hand users can transfer their knowledge about workflows from other apps that use a similiar style. Your app will be easier to use.

### Development Time & Speed

Also I don't understand how not using a framework would *save* you time rather than *cost* you time. The only time thats ever going to be true is if you have design ideas so specific that you don't end up using any of the styles provided by the framework or you spend so much time customizing the styles of the framework that you could have done it from scratch aswell. In either of these cases you need a developer that is heavily / purely dedicated to design & UX and it doesn't sound like you would wanna do that.

### Theme vs. Framework

Lastly you should ask yourself where you draw the line between framework and "theme",  and why you are so eager to distinguish them. What would be the point of finding a "theme" and then manually applying the style to all your components rather than using a framework that allready provides you with components that are styled appropiately?

P.S.: afaik Material-Ui is definetly a thing for React Native and has a pretty big following too.

Comment: **Design:**
xtr thank you so much for your very well explained point of view. I was thinking about to use have the benefits of professional design, good UX, well fluidity and animation got from the theme, i will not get it i use a theme with pure CSS? My problem to use some framework is to the encrease the complexy of the project, what i dont want, does a framework like Material UI does not increase to much the complexy of the project? The main concern is to keep it simple to maintain and fast to develop after have some experience in CSS.

Comment: **Development time:**
I thought the pure css using only styled-components lib would save my time because i heard 2 experience front-end developers talking they take more time searching how to use the framework and this type of thing than do by they with pure CSS using onle styled-components to help. As i work at this project at full time and this is my job, i think at some in some time i will get the point wich is faster developer with pure css, does it not happen or it take to much time to get at this point?

Comment: **Theme vs Framework:**
I am not eager to distiguish them i'm just avoiding to use some frameork because of the previous points mentioned (complexity to others developers maintain, development speed after have some experience and also thought my costumer would get a good UX if i use a professional theme, my intention is not to apply my style to the components of the theme, its just to change the layout to offer what the bussiness need). Please, tell me what points you see diferent, i appreciate so much the help of the comunity.